# Error en RichText en Flutter

Tags: web, flutter, text

Hola tengo el siguiente problema en un programa que estoy realizando en Flutter para web.

Tengo que poner una linea de texto con diferentes colores en las letras o colores de fondo (Lo que tendria que salir es la fila 1 y lo que sale es la 2)
[image: Como se ve en la imagen la linea 1 es la que tendria que ser y la segunda lo que sale]

el problema es que al poner la "f" junto con la "i" o la "l", se duplica el color de fondo asi como las letras. El codigo que empleo esta a continuacion.

```
 RichText(
              text: TextSpan(
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 28.0, color: Colors.black),
                  children: <TextSpan>[
                    TextSpan(
                        text: "Tiene que ser solo una letra ",
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green[100])),
                    TextSpan(
                      text: 'f',
                      //text: '$_counter',
                      style: TextStyle(backgroundColor: Colors.amber[100]),
                    ),
                    TextSpan(
                        text: 'i, solo', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black))
                  ]),
            ),
```

Gracias

Comment: que raro, solo pasa en web? en mobile funciona bien ?

Comment: Sí, solo para web y en compilación para canvaskit en compilación html se soluciona pero no me sirve por que me desplaza el texto aunque no tenga un espacio.

Answer (score 1):

Después de mucho tiempo encontre la solución, que no tiene que ver on la programación. Es por culpa de la ligatura en el texto. Es decir hoy que emplear fuentes que sean en mono espacio.

```
TextSpan(
  text: _.initialPartText.value,
  style: GoogleFonts.droidSansMono(
   textStyle:                                          
      TextStyle(color: Colors.green[100]))),
```

Comment: Qué bueno que hayas encontrado solución y no hayas dejado tu pregunta sin responder :) No olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta (y darle formato al código). Y si quieres obtener tu primera medalla, haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.